# Update/Insert 15 million records in oracle database

Tags: plsql, parallel-processing, proc, oracle9i

There is a requirement is my project to insert 15 million records in a table after doing some validations , and this should be done in 20 minutes.

Source table is a staging table which receives data from other applications. Now from this staging table we have to insert data into one of the base tables after validations. And when this process ends we have to insert the records from staging table into two separate history tables.

First insert's time should be 20 minutes.
And for next two inserts combined time should be 20 minutes.

All four tables in same db, in same schema.
I'm using Pro*C for validations in case 1 but in second insertions there is a plsql package.

Can anyone help me with any suggestions, database is oracle 9i. Also what is the maximum number of records that can be process in 20 minutes?

Comment: Where are the rows coming from?  Are you really using Oracle 9i, a version that is at least 5 major revisions old and which hasn't been supported in years?  How, exactly, are you doing the load today?  There are lots of possible architectures here that would seem to be more than sufficient.  Oracle does a demo regularly where they load a TB of data into a data warehouse running on an Exadata machine during a 1 hour presentation.

Comment: Hi Justin. These rows are coming from another application through an ETL tool. Yes we are using 9i because whole system is too old. For my test purpose I'm just inserting any record manually by my own test data preperation scripts. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: FYI Today I tried with DOP 10 on tables only insertion in one table took 19 minutes. But due to large amount of batches running at night we can't do a lot parallelism.

Comment: OK, so there is an ETL tool.  What tool?  Is that tool doing set-based operations?  Or row-by-row operations?  Does it pull all the data to a machine where the ETL tool runs?  Or does it operate in the database?  A set-based insert from one table to another in the database should be pretty darn quick.

Comment: That tool inserts data into our staging table through out the day. At night we have to run  2 batches for mentioned processes. Sorry but I don't have much information about the questions you asked about inserting in our db as our main concern is to take data from staging table and process in 20 mins each.

Comment: But that tool does not operate within our database. That is for data transfer between two separate database

Comment: OK.  If I am understanding correctly, the process that we are talking about here is taking data from one table (a staging table) and moving it to a different table using custom code.  Not an ETL tool.  Is that correct?  If so, are you doing a single set-based `insert`?  Or are you trying to write row-by-row processing?  You mention `Pro*C`.  Are you by chance reading a single row from the staging table, sending it over the network to a client machine where `Pro*C` is running, then turning around and sending that data back over the network as a single-row insert to the destination table?

Comment: For the first part you got it right no ETL tool is involved. When we are inserting into Base table after validations it will be done by Pro*C ; row by row; 12 threads. And in case of insertion in history tables we are inserting into sets by using plsql package. Is this helpful?

Comment: That's helpful.  Posting code would be really helpful.  You want to be doing set-based inserts and you want to avoid bringing any data to the client particularly if the client is on a different machine.  Beyond that, it's pretty hard to offer suggestions without looking at code.

Comment: Yeah but for the second process do we need code? As it's some copyright thing so I'm afraid it will be difficult to share the pro*c code. But second batch is simply an insertion. I understood your suggestion for set based insertion in pro*c. I have to fetch everything at once and insert in one go after validating in pro*c.

Comment: If you are worried about performance, don't fetch data from the database to the client application.  Do the validations in the database by having the `Pro*C` application issue SQL statements.  If you absolutely positively need row-by-row processing (very, very few people really do), do them in PL/SQL so that you're at least not pulling data over the network.  You don't need to post the exact code you are using.  But you need to post code that replicates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of data you need to work with. I don't know how much time this would take in 9i, I use 11g (free edition on a cheap laptop), the insert below (of 15,000,000 very simple rows, a single numeric column) took less than 20 **seconds**:

```
SQL> create table a ( col number );

Table created.
Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

SQL> insert into a
  2  select u.x + v.y
  3  from            (select level x from dual connect by level <= 15000) u
  4       cross join (select level y from dual connect by level <=  1000) v;

15000000 rows created.    
Elapsed: 00:00:19.46

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select count(*) from a;

  COUNT(*)
----------
  15000000

1 row selected.    
Elapsed: 00:00:01.36
```

Comment: Thanks maths guy, but I have to take data from one table to another

Comment: @SinghGaurav - that is exactly why you need to share more details. It is one thing to insert "numbers" and another to insert 3000 character strings. It is one thing to generate the entries on the fly and another to obtain them from a join of eight tables. Etc. I see you added a few more details, but I am afraid that's still not enough.

Comment: Let me know what details are required. I will try to share them.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we decided to insert into two history tables in parallel using multi-threading, this is a simple INSERT query.
For second scenario, Pro*C is processing each record one by one,so, it can't be completed in given time. Still we have implemented maximum threads that can't hinder other processes and some degree of parallel in our Pl/SQL part.

Thank you all for suggesions.